# Complexity of counting 3-colourings of planar bounded degree graphs

Tags: graph-theory, counting-complexity, planar-graphs, graph-colouring, bounded-degree

The following are known:

1. It is #P-complete to count the number of 3-colourings of a planar graph (with respect to randomized reductions) [1].
2. For all $d\geq 3$, it is #P-complete to count the number of 3-colourings of a graph with maximum degree $d$ [2].

*Correction (27-04-21):* Result 1 is only with respect to randomized reductions (NOT deterministic reductions) in both Barbanchon [1] and Hunt et al. (unpublished work I think; details of construction appears in other papers).

**What about the complexity of counting the number of 3-colourings of a planar bounded degree graph $G$?**
(say, $\Delta(G)\leq 3$ or $\Delta(G)\leq 4$)

It is a bonus if bipartiteness (or girth) also comes into the picture. Counting 3-colouring of a bipartite graph is #P-complete [3]. Result 2 above is improved to triangle-free graphs of maximum degree $d$ by Greenhill [4].

**References**
[1] *Barbanchon, Régis*, [**On unique graph 3-colorability and parsimonious reductions in the plane**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2004.02.003), Theor. Comput. Sci. 319, No. 1-3, 455-482 (2004). [ZBL1043.05043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1043.05043).

[2] *Bubley, Russ; Dyer, Martin; Greenhill, Catherine; Jerrum, Mark*, [**On approximately counting colorings of small degree graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0097539798338175), SIAM J. Comput. 29, No. 2, 387-400 (1998). [ZBL0937.05041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0937.05041).

[3] *Linial, Nathan*, [**Hard enumeration problems in geometry and combinatorics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0607036), SIAM J. Algebraic Discrete Methods 7, 331-335 (1986). [ZBL0596.68041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0596.68041).

[4] *Greenhill, Catherine*, [**The complexity of counting colourings and independent sets in sparse graphs and hypergraphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/PL00001601), Comput. Complexity 9, No. 1, 52-72 (2000). [ZBL0963.68082](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0963.68082).